# Display following users posts

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, posts

So I have a project that I'm working on where you can "follow" another user, and view their posts, along with other users. Like Facebook. Something like this

```
Bob: I love SO
Alex: I love SO too
Ally: Me three!
```

So this is what I'm doing so far. I'm selecting the people the signed in user is following, all of which are stored in a table called `followers`. Here's what it looks like

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+
| id  | follow_from | follow_to |
+-----+-------------+-----------+
| 319 | bob         | alex      |
| 320 | ally        | alex      |
| 320 | alex        | ally      |
+-----+-------------+-----------+
```

As you can see it displays the user and who they're following. So this is how I retrieve a list of who you're following

```
SELECT * FROM followers WHERE follow_from = :username
```

Now that will return

```
Bob
Alex
Ally
```

Now onto the posts. I store the posts in another table called "posts". This is what that looks like

```
+----+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| id | post_user | post_ip | post_date | post_content | post_likes |
+----+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+
|  1 | alex      | ::1     |           | I like cats  | 0          |
+----+-----------+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

So I'd assume that *both* `Bob` and `Ally` see alex's post. The issue I'm having is retrieving the posts and basically *merging* them together. Since my posts are in another table I couldn't find a way to figure out which post is which.

I've tried this

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE followed_user=:username ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

But couldn't figure out a way to use `:username` with multiple username. Like the followers. So basically my question is, how can I display multiple posts, from multiple users, on one wall. Or if anyone can solve how I can select posts from multiple people you're following.

Just to add on when I do `SELECT * FROM followers WHERE follow_from = :username` and run

```
$posts = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $posts[] =  array(
    'follow_to' => $row['follow_to']
);
}
```

And do

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
            echo $post['follow_to'];
}
```

I get a list of the followers, so I'd assume this will have something to do with retrieval of the posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for JOIN/Subquery,

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    posts
WHERE
    post_user IN 
    (
        SELECT follow_to FROM followers WHERE follow_from = :user
    )
```

**Update**

If you'd like to load a list of posts by a single person as well as the followers,

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    posts
WHERE
    post_user IN 
    (
        SELECT 
            follow_from 
        FROM 
            followers 
        WHERE 
            follow_to = :user 
            OR
            follow_from = :user 
    )
```

Comment: What if I also wanted to so the users posts in the feed as well. So I'd be Bob. And I'd want to see Ally, Alex, _and_ my posts. How would I go about this?

Comment: Not sure if I have to tag you. @J A

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: When I run the query I only see _other_ users posts. I'd like to see my post _along_ with other posts. Like I'd see Ally's posts, and Alex's posts, _and_ my posts.